# How to obtain all the phone numbers in each row of a df, using phonenumbers Python Library?

Tags: python, pandas, python-phonenumber

I want to create a column with all valid phone numbers available in each row of the `text` column in a data frame using Python's `phonenumber` library.

```
complains = ['If you validate your data, your confirmation number is 1-23-456-789, for a teacher you will be debited on the 3rd of each month 41.99, you will pay for the remaining 3 services offered:n/a',
             'EMAIL VERIFYED, 12345 1st STUDENT 400 88888 2nd STUDENT 166.93 Your request has been submitted and your confirmation number is 1-234-567-777 speed is increased to 250MB $80.99 BILLING CYCLE 18',
             'ADJUSTMENT FROM NOVEMBER TO MAY $80.99 Appointment for equipment change 7878940142']

complainsdf = pd.DataFrame(complains, index =['1', '2', '3'], columns =['text'])
```

I tried the code below. But I didn't get the results I expected.

```
complainsdf['tel'] = complainsdf.apply(lambda row: 
    phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(row['text'], "US"), axis=1)
```

`complainsdf['tel'][0]` gives me  the following output:
`<phonenumbers.phonenumbermatcher.PhoneNumberMatcher at 0x2623ebfddf0>` and not the expected phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `tel` can contains multiple phone numbers per row. They are stored as an object of type `phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher`.

To extract the raw phone number, you have to iterate over the object, with a loop. For instance, you can do:

```
def get_phone_numbers(x):
    # Extract the phone numbers from the text
    nums = phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(x, "US")
    # Convert the phone number format
    return [phonenumbers.format_number(num.number, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164) for num in nums]

complainsdf['tel'] = complainsdf['text'].apply(get_phone_numbers)
complainsdf
```

---

```
                                                 text   tel
1   If you validate your data, your confirmation n...   []
2   EMAIL VERIFYED, 12345 1st STUDENT 400 88888 2n...   []
3   ADJUSTMENT FROM NOVEMBER TO MAY $80.99 Appoint...   [+17878940142]
```

I found the way to convert the format with `PhoneNumberFormat.E164` in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/). Maybe you have to adapt it to your case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works. However I will wait if any user proposes an answer that does not need two different steps.

Comment: Ok, I grouped the two steps into one. I edited the answer.